# Achieving friendly URLs and multiple nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 3, it is my wish to create a URL structure that looks like:

```
http://example.org/learn/cooking/cooking-101/can-anybody-cook
```

and that corresponds to the following controllers:

```
http://example.org/learn/subject/module/lesson
```

The associations will look like:

```
Subject has many Modules
Module belongs to Subject
```

and

```
Module has many Lessons
Lessons belongs to Module
```

*Learn is simply a hub or a dashboard and will list all of the Subjects. There will be no associations with the other controllers.*

I know that in the [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), they warn against making multiple nested resources like so:

```
resources :subjects do
  resources :modules do
    resources :lessons
  end
end
```

That's about all I know. I am a little stuck. Could someone please help me with the routing?

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd go about this, rather than nesting resources, which I don't believe is necessary in this case is to create custom show routes for each of subjects, modules and lessons.

So I'd set up each resource as follows:

```
resources :subjects, :except => [:show]
resources :modules, :except => [:show]
resources :lessons, :except => [:show]
```

Then match the show routes explicitely:

```
match '/learn/:subject/:module/:lesson' => 'lessons#show', :as => 'show_lesson'
match '/learn/:subject/:module' => 'modules#show', :as => 'show_module'
match '/learn/:subject' => 'subjects#show', :as => 'show_subjects'
```

That will give you more granularity over defining routes for show (which is the normal action you want to customise the url for).

Now depending on your requirements you may still want to nest the resources, but hopefully that gives you some ideas.

By the way I name my show_xxx routes with the show_ just to clarify that they're named routes, and to avoid any possible collisions in case I decide to use the show on the resource.

Comment: In the first URL and taking :subject as an example, would that just show the ID? Could I somehow display subject.permalink there instead? Granted I have that attribute set.

Comment: Yes, if you take the show_lesson named route above, you'll get :subject, :module, and :lesson in the params collection, you can then use these to find on the permalink rather than the id.

Comment: For the resources rather than the named routes, they'll be using :id as normal, however you can override the behaviour of object.id by overriding to_param. Here's a little article about overriding to_param if you're interested: http://jroller.com/obie/entry/seo_optimization_of_urls_in

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I've implemented what you have said. Unfortunately when I go to /subjects/new and try to save a Subject I get 'No route matches [GET] "/subjects/1"'. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, because you've removed the default show route, you'll need to change any calls to subject_path to use the new show_subject (just noticed I pluralised that by mistake in my example above). So in your create action you'll have a `redirect_to subject_path( @subject )` or similar, you'll need to change this to something like `redirect_to show_subject_path(:subject => @subject.permalink)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use routing [namespaces](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) and [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem with specifying custom path in this case. Smth like following should help:

```
namespace :learn do
  resources :subjects, path: '' do
    resources :modules, path: '' do
      resources :lessons
    end
  end
end
```

For more information about installing `friendly_id` please read [rails quick-start](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#rails-quickstart). You should add `slug` column and extend `friendly_id` module in your classes (`Subject`, `Module`, `Lesson`). See [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid) also.